# How to erase last digit in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
    return val.slice(0, -1);    
});
```

I want to create a C button in my calculator which can delete last entered digit..

Comment: Post the HTML of your calculator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)** with callback function to update the value based on old value

```js
$('#delete').click(function() {
  $('#text').val(function(i, val) {
    return val.slice(0, -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<button id="delete">C</utton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the new value after slicing:

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
    var v = $('targetInput').val().slice(0, -1);
    $('targetInput').val(v);
});
```